# BaseAdapter postion changed when call notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

i have a BaseAdapter like this . let's say , i just have four rows .

i will call setId for this four convertView with the posttion .
and i will call notifyDataSetChanged() somewhere (i define a button at top ,click the button will call notifyDataSetChanged), when  notifyDataSetChanged called , the four rows will be called by getView() . at the getView() , i will print the id(old position) and the new position . as the rows have no change , i think the position will not change . they will be the same . but the turth is not that .

the print :

```
D/BasePhotoFragment(19230): position:0
D/BasePhotoFragment(19230): old id :3
D/BasePhotoFragment(19230): new id :0
D/BasePhotoFragment(19230): position:1
D/BasePhotoFragment(19230): old id :2
D/BasePhotoFragment(19230): new id :1
D/BasePhotoFragment(19230): position:2
D/BasePhotoFragment(19230): old id :1
D/BasePhotoFragment(19230): new id :2
D/BasePhotoFragment(19230): position:3
D/BasePhotoFragment(19230): old id :0
D/BasePhotoFragment(19230): new id :3
```

could anyone told me why ? thanks , bellow is the adapter code .

```
public class PhotosGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private Context mContext ;
private List<PhotoEntity> listEntity ;
private int mLinePhotos;
private LinearLayout.LayoutParams mphotoParams = new android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);

private final class ViewHolder{
    public List<ImageView> imgs;
}

public PhotosGridAdapter(Context ctx,List<PhotoEntity> entities) {
    this.mContext = ctx ;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
    mLinePhotos = Utils.getPhotosNumOfLine(ctx);
    listEntity = entities;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listEntity != null ? listEntity.size() / mLinePhotos  : 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    if( position < listEntity.size() )
    return listEntity.get(position);
    else
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Log.d(TAG,"position:"+position);
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_grid_photos_container, null);
            ....
    convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
    holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }


   int old_id = convertView.getId();

   Log.d(TAG,"old id :"+old_id);
   Log.d(TAG,"new id :"+position);

   if(old_id == position)
       return convertView;

       convertView.setId(position);

       ..... do some bind .
   return convertView;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you call notifyDataSetChanged() the views will be refreshed, either re-created or recycled, in other words, the getView method will be called again for every visible row.

You should call it only when the model has changed, in your case *listEntity*, only if new elements were added to it or the data from the elements already in the list has changed.

If you are inflating 2 different layouts, be aware to use implement the method getItemViewType() and [getViewTypeCount()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getViewTypeCount%28%29) this will guaranteed that the given 'convertView' parameter given on the getView() method is corresponding to the one you should be using for the given position. So in your case, although the code seems incomplete, I believe that you are receiving the wrong convertView parameter for the position being recycled, due to this issue, that is why you have different id's in the logs.

Comment: i don't know where the code is wrong . i just inflating 1 layout .